# Getting reputation notification too late

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-profile

This morning I asked question, and forgot a bit about it. However, a couple of hours later, I found a possible answer to it, and answered my own question. To my surprise, I saw that I had two upvotes on the question, but I never got any notification of that. I mean, there was no green "+5" or "+10" in the upper panel, where it should be.

Looking at my profile, those reputation points were awarded on my profile, and iirc, my total reputation was also increased. However, even when I opened the achievements tab, there was no notion of the increased rep. I could have made a screenshot of the awarded rep on my profile page, and missing notification in the achievements tab, but I didn't. However, I am sure there was delay (as in minutes to hours, not just mere seconds).

Now, just before I wrote this question, the green "+10" arrived in my achievements tab (hence I wrote this question). I never ever noticed this delay before. Was there something happening in the achievement system or something?

Comment: It's probably - everybody say it with me now... 1... *2...* **3...** ***Caching!***

Comment: [Caching on SE... not for real](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how), [blame it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/227881) and [blame it for real](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Okay. Clear. I was just curious because I never witnessed this particular problem before. But it is indeed reasonable that caching is the problem.

Comment: I noticed this the other day too. You're not the only one.

Comment: This is the reason: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297483/reputation-not-showing-up-in-the-achievements-tab-anymore